# Play-Slick generating errors in routes

Tags: mysql, playframework, slick, slick-2.0, play-slick

I was trying to get started with Slick and Play Framework but I keep getting those errors.

I have added slick, play-slick and mysql connector to library dependencies and also the following lines to application.conf:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver= "slick.driver.MySQLDriver"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:mysql://cronline.pl"
```

I get the following errors:

```
Information:Play 2 Compiler: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
Information:Play 2 Compiler: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Loading project definition from /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/project
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Set current project to Scrapper (in build file:/home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/)
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Updating {file:/home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/}root...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.11;1.0.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.18.2-GA ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-iteratees_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-stm#scala-stm_2.11;0.7 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.2.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-functional_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-datacommons_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving joda-time#joda-time;2.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.joda#joda-convert;1.6 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.3.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.3.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.3.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.11;1.0.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving io.netty#netty;3.9.8.Final ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.netty#netty-http-pipelining;1.1.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.6 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.slf4j#jul-to-slf4j;1.7.6 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.slf4j#jcl-over-slf4j;1.7.6 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.1.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.3.4 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j_2.11;2.3.4 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving xerces#xercesImpl;2.11.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.4.01 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving javax.transaction#jta;1.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.jolbox#bonecp;0.8.0.RELEASE ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.google.guava#guava;15.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.h2database#h2;1.3.175 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving tyrex#tyrex;1.0.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#anorm_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.jsuereth#scala-arm_2.11;1.4 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-lang.plugins#scala-continuations-library_2.11;1.0.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving net.sf.ehcache#ehcache-core;2.6.8 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-ws_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.ning#async-http-client;1.8.15 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-core;1.2.1.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-commonshttp4;1.2.1.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.0.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.1.18 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.11;3.0.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.6 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.reactivestreams#reactive-streams;1.0.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-slick_2.11;1.0.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.zaxxer#HikariCP;2.3.7 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.10 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.19.0-GA ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc-api_2.11;2.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play_2.11;2.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-iteratees_2.11;2.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.3.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.11;2.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-functional_2.11;2.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-datacommons_2.11;2.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving joda-time#joda-time;2.7 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.joda#joda-convert;1.7 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.6 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.5.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.5.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.5.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype#jackson-datatype-jdk8;2.5.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype#jackson-datatype-jsr310;2.5.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-netty-utils;2.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.12 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.slf4j#jul-to-slf4j;1.7.12 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.slf4j#jcl-over-slf4j;1.7.12 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.11;1.1.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.4 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.1.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.1.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11;2.3.11 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j_2.11;2.3.11 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.10 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.google.inject#guice;4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving javax.inject#javax.inject;1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.google.inject.extensions#guice-assistedinject;4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.google.inject.extensions#extensions-parent;4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving junit#junit;4.11 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.specs2#specs2-core_2.11;2.3.12 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.specs2#specs2-matcher_2.11;2.3.12 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.specs2#specs2-common_2.11;2.3.12 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.11;7.0.6 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-concurrent_2.11;7.0.6 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.11;7.0.6 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.specs2#specs2-junit_2.11;2.3.12 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.specs2#specs2-mock_2.11;2.3.12 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.mockito#mockito-core;1.9.5 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.objenesis#objenesis;1.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.specs2#specs2-matcher-extra_2.11;2.3.12 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.specs2#specs2-analysis_2.11;2.3.12 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.specs2#classycle;1.4.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.novocode#junit-interface;0.11-RC1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;2.0.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-festassert;0.9.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-core;0.9.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-java;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-android-driver;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-remote-driver;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving cglib#cglib-nodep;2.1_3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.json#json;20080701 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-api;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.3.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-exec;1.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving net.java.dev.jna#platform;3.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-chrome-driver;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-htmlunit-driver;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.13 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving xalan#xalan;2.7.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving xalan#serializer;2.7.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.3.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit-core-js;2.13 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.19 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving net.sourceforge.cssparser#cssparser;0.9.11 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.w3c.css#sac;1.3 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-websocket;8.1.12.v20130726 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.12.v20130726 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.12.v20130726 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.12.v20130726 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-firefox-driver;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-ie-driver;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-iphone-driver;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-safari-driver;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.webbitserver#webbit;0.4.14 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-support;2.39.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.easytesting#fest-assert;1.4 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.easytesting#fest-util;1.1.6 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.11;2.3.9 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-doc_2.11;1.1.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.pegdown#pegdown;1.4.0 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-java;1.1.5 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-core;1.1.5 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm;4.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-tree;4.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-analysis;4.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-util;4.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.4 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.1 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11;1.0.2 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Resolving jline#jline;2.11 ...
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Done updating.
Information:Play 2 Compiler:  Compiling 5 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/target/scala-2.11/classes...
Information:Module "root" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:28.05.15 09:03 - Compilation completed with 54 errors and 0 warnings in 16s 761ms
Error:Play 2 Compiler:  GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
Error:Play 2 Compiler:  GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
/home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes
    Error:Error:Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes: value HandlerInvokerFactory is not a member of object play.core.Router
 /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes: value HandlerInvokerFactory is not a member of object play.core.Router
    Error:Error:Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes: value queryString is not a member of object play.core.Router
 /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: type ReverseRouteContext
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value ReverseRouteContext
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value dynamicString
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (6)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: not found: value ReverseRouteContext
 GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value ReverseRouteContext
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value dynamicString
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (6)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: not found: object ReverseRouteContext
 GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: type JavascriptReverseRoute
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: value JavascriptReverseRoute
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: type JavascriptReverseRoute
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value JavascriptReverseRoute
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (6)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: not found: type JavascriptReverseRoute
 GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
    Error:Error:line (6)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: not found: value JavascriptReverseRoute
 GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: type JavascriptReverseRoute
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value JavascriptReverseRoute
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: type HandlerRef is not a member of package play.api.mvc
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: value HandlerDef
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: type HandlerRef is not a member of package play.api.mvc
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value HandlerDef
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (6)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: type HandlerRef is not a member of package play.api.mvc
 GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
    Error:Error:line (6)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: not found: value HandlerDef
 GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: type HandlerRef is not a member of package play.api.mvc
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value HandlerDef
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes: value queryString is not a member of object play.core.Router
 /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes: not found: value ReverseRouteContext
    Error:Error:Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes: value setPrefix is not a member of play.core.Router.Routes
 /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: not found: value Route
    Error:Error:line (6)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: not found: value PathPattern
 GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
    Error:Error:line (6)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: not found: value StaticPart
 GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
    Error:Error:line (6)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: not found: value createInvoker
 GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value Route
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value PathPattern
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value StaticPart
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value DynamicPart
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value createInvoker
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value fakeValue
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value Route
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value PathPattern
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value StaticPart
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value DynamicPart
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value createInvoker
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value fakeValue
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: value Route
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: value PathPattern
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: value StaticPart
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: value DynamicPart
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: value createInvoker
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: value fakeValue
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (6)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:6: not found: value call
 GET        /                    controllers.Application.currentDayIndex
    Error:Error:line (7)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:7: not found: value call
 GET        /:data               controllers.Application.index(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (9)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:9: not found: value call
 GET        /data/:data               controllers.Application.getJsonedData(data: String)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: value call
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
    Error:Error:line (12)Play 2 Compiler:  /home/haito/IdeaProjects/Scrapper/conf/routes:12: not found: value Param
 GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Comment: same here. Did you solved the problem ?

Comment: @Regis I gave up. Unfortunately i don't have time Tinker with it just to get started. I tried mongo (with reactive mongo and it's sweet)

Answer (score 3):

You most likely have incompatible versions of play framework and play-slick plugin.

See compatibility table to make sure everything is all right (taken from [play-slick readme](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick#releases)):

[image: play-slick compatibility table]

**Edit:**

I had the same issue when using play 2.3.x and play-slick 1.0